# find and replace

Tags: regex, shell, sed

Find:

```
regexp1 **sometext** regexp2
```

Replace with:

```
newregexp1 **sometext** newregexp2
```

Here, I do not want `**sometext**` to be modified.
That is to say, if I have the following lines in a file:

```
Hello somebody! Have a good day.
Hello somebodyelse! Have a good day.
```

I want the output to be:

```
Bye somebody! Good night.
Bye somebodyelse! Good night.
```

My regular expression search would be of the following form:

```
Hello .*! Have a good day.
```

How can I use the `\1` keyword with `sed` (or any linux tool) to accomplish this.
Please help me with the actual command syntax.

Also, if you have a way to do this in notepad++, please let me know.

Thanks for any Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sed 's/Hello \(.*\)! Have a good day./Bye \1! Good night./' MyInputFile > MyOutputFile
```

Comment: Note that you can perform the replacement in place on the file using `sed -i 's/pat1/pat2/'` - best to check that your replacement is right first though (output to stdout, probably).

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Hello somebody! Have a good day" | sed -e 's/Hello \(.*\) Have a good day/Bye \1 Good night./'
```

But I sense some misconception in how regexps work, since you're using "regexp1" in the source text. Regexps are **patterns** which describe strings, not the strings themselves.